# Itune conect Warning For iOS 9 Application OS-

Tags: ios, applet, app-store-connect

My App iOS version 9, it was Working perfectly before 2019, but in jan itune connect showing warning of iOS versions, i uploaded build it does't effect on uploading process, but i am afraid is it will work on old devices ios9 or not. what should i do?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your Xcode 9 or Xcode 7 or Xcode 10 to Xcode 10.1 and add respective SDKS to the project. Which will include 12.0 SDK's automatically.

Comment: means no need to update my development Target, where I set ios 9.

Comment: @AyazAkbar Yup no need to update you deployment target.